# Why does the following expression return true?

Tags: java, operators, short-circuiting

I am having a tough time in understanding the precedence of the short circuit operators in Java. As per the short circuit behavior, the right part of the expression "true || true" shouldn't matter here because once the first part of the "&&" condition is evaluated as "false", the rest of the expression should have not been evaluated.

But, when executing the following piece of code, I see the result declared as "true". Could someone explain this to me?

```
    public class ExpressionTest{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean result1 = false && true || true;
        System.out.println(result1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) on operators. The table clearly shows that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

So,

```
false && true || true;
```

is evaluated as:

```
(false && true) || true;
```

Rest I think you can evaluate on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I now understand why the expression evaluated to "true". But, why makes the compiler choose the evaluation strategy as (false && true) || true. Instead, it could have just ignored the rest of the statement after seeing a "false" just before the "&&" operator?

Comment: @sunsin1985. Java evaluates expression left to right. That is so.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it to me.

Answer (score 4):

From [The JAVA turorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

> Operators on the same line have equal precedence. When operators of
>   equal precedence appear in the same expression, a rule must govern
>   which is evaluated first. All binary operators except for the
>   assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; assignment
>   operators are evaluated right to left

Therefor, the compiler parse it as

```
boolean result1 = (false && true) || true;
```

Therefor, `A || true` return `true` regardless of `A` value.

To get the desirable expression do as follow:

```
boolean result1 = false && (true || true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The Java Tutorial makes it clear for me now, the left to right evaluation is the key here.